# How GDB deals with big (>1 Gb) debug files?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I have a problem debugging C++ application using remote GDB session that codebase is big, and therefore it  contains (when compiled with "-O2', '-g', '-DNDEBUG'" flags) a big file with debug information (1.1 Gb).

Unfortunately, I can't just use partial symbol tables during debugging since all the time debugger skips the part of the application, and I'm unable to set breakpoints there and see the code while debugging.

As the solution for this issue, I execute following command after I've got connected to target:

```
symbol-file -readnow [path-to-file-with-debugging-info]
```

This expands full symbol tables. But in this case GDB simply runs out of memory hitting 13 Gb or even more RAM (while I have only 16 Gb available on my machine). This problem is already listed in [GDB Wiki](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/SymbolHandling) and known.

My question is how to deal with GDB in this case, when I need full symbol tables, but GDB requires an enorm amount of memory in order to expand it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Partial symbol tables are a gdb optimization.  If they don't work, then that is a gdb bug that you ought to file.  Normal users should never need `-readnow` -- it is more of a gdb developer option and/or bug-workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since dealing with big debug files is GDB's weakness, the optimal way in this case was to reduce the size of *.dbg file with help of having debug symbols not for the all application modules, but only for those where debugging will actually occur.

In this case with ~150 mb *.dbg file and using of DS-5 debugger I needed only 2.5 Gb RAM which is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use gold linker with `--compress-debug-sections=zlib` option. This will reduce the size of debug info. gdb can read compressed debug info since 7.0 version.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, but unfortunately I have to tend using common build environment, and there it's not allowed to use other linker/compiler/etc.