# How to get the latest version of gdb in android-ndk?

Tags: android, android-ndk, gdb, gdbserver

I have the weird issue when debugging with ndk-gdb (v7.6) which partially described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490854/how-gdb-deals-with-big-1-gb-debug-files), and one of my ideas to resolve it was to update to the latest gdb version that is [currently 7.9](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/download/).

I've downloaded the latest Android-ndk (which is currently android-ndk-r10d) but found out that it also contains gdb 7.6 (for arm-linux-androideabi-4.9) which comes from year 2013, and since then there were many optimizations and bugfixes that could have effect on the issue I'm facing.

Is there any way to somehow get a newer (ideally - the latest) gdb version for android-ndk?

Thanks!

Comment: There are source code repositories for GDB (and binutils, etc) in AOSP.  You could see if those are up-to-date, or at least use them to figure out how to start porting an upstream version to Android.

Comment: Realistically though, this is probably not going to be the fastest way to solve whatever problem there is in the program you are trying to develop.  Are you really hitting the issue listed?  In an android app???

Answer (score 0):

I've modified some code of GDB, both 7.6 and 7.8, I've found that there are bugs in GDBSERVER version 7.8, and I had to turn back to modify v7.6. So I think maybe unfounded bugs is the reason why NDK still use v7.6, and I recommend you to use what NDK choice.

Anyway, if you do need a updated version, you can download the source code of GDB from it's official site, and compile it yourself. Make sure you have cross compile tools and use them correctly.